# Rails ActiveRecord - Search on Multiple Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, activerecord, sql-injection

I'm implementing a simple search function that should check for a string in either the username, last_name and first_name. I've seen this ActiveRecord method on an old RailsCast:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form

```
find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
```

But how do I make it so that it searches for the keyword in name, last_name and first name and returns the record if the one of the fields matched the term?

I'm also wondering if the code on the RailsCast is prone to SQL injections?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I assumed your model name is Model - just replace it with your real model name when you do the actual query:

```
Model.where("name LIKE ? OR last_name LIKE ? OR first_name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%","%#{search}%","%#{search}%")
```

About your worries about SQL injections - both of code snippets are immune to SQL injections. As long as you do not directly embed strings into your WHERE clause you are fine. An example for injection-prone code would be:

```
Model.where("name LIKE '#{params[:name]}'")
```

Comment: What if the controller is changed to pass the whole `params` rather than just `params[:search]` and in our query we use `"%#{params[:search]}%"` instead of `"%#{search}%"`. Is that still immune to SQL injections?

Comment: @Dennis yes it is. As long as you are using ? and passing extra argument to replace them in the query you are fine.

Comment: Thanks @ErezRabih. What about using hashes? E.g. `where(name: params[:name])`

Comment: This query works like a charm! (using active record 5)

Comment: Having those three params is really ugly. Better to name it like this `Model.where("x ILIKE :query OR y ILIKE :query", query: "%#{params[:query]}%")`

Answer (score 13):

Although the selected answer will work, I noticed that it breaks if you try to type a search "Raul Riera" because it will fail on both cases, because Raul Riera is not either my first name or my last name.. is my first and last name... I solved it by doing

```
Model.where("lower(first_name || ' ' || last_name) LIKE ?", "%#{search.downcase}%")
```

Comment: I found this answer more useful. Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `ILIKE` rather than downcase? Let the DB handle it.

Comment: It doesn't work when last_name or first_name equal to nil, if so, you need set default empty string value to first and last name

Answer (score 2):

With Arel, you can avoid writing the SQL manually with something like this:

```
Model.where(
  %i(name first_name last_name)
    .map { |field| Model.arel_table[field].matches("%#{query}%")}
    .inject(:or)
)
```

This would be particularly useful if the list of fields to match against was dynamic.

Comment: you forgot the closing } on the .map line, adapted it

Answer (score 1):

A more generic solution for searching in all fields of the model would be like this

```
def search_in_all_fields model, text
  model.where(
    model.column_names
      .map {|field| "#{field} like '%#{text}%'" }
      .join(" or ")
  )
end
```

Or better as a scope in the model itself

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :search_in_all_fields, ->(text){
    where(
      column_names
        .map {|field| "#{field} like '%#{text}%'" }
        .join(" or ")
    )
  }
end
```

You would just need to call it like this

```
Model.search_in_all_fields "test"
```

Before you start.., no, sql injection would probably not work here but still better and shorter

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :search_all_fields, ->(text){
    where("#{column_names.join(' || ')} like ?", "%#{text}%")
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is:

```
Model.where("attr_a ILIKE :query OR attr_b ILIKE :query", query: "%#{query}%")
```