# Rails Mongoid - Search on multiple attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, mongoid

I recently started to use Mongodb with rails so I don't know if is possible to do a NoSQL query like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22976269/3543115):

```
Model.where("lower(first_name || ' ' || last_name) LIKE ?", "%#{search.downcase}%")
```

I want to type a search with first name and last name in the same string, for example: "John Smith"

Is this possible with Mongoid querying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use javascript expressions, see this page:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/

Comment: It works! `Model.where("this.first_name this.last_name" == /search/i)`, thank you!

Comment: Sorry but the correct code is: `Model.where("this.first_name + ' ' + this.last_name == '#{search}'")`, and yet i have not succeeded use Regex instead String